# How should I store list of single values?

Tags: ruby, file, csv

I am currently writing a Ruby script to manage my dotfiles. I want to keep a list of the tracked dotfiles, and am not quite sure how to go about this.

The thing is that the list would be so simple, e.g

```
tmux.conf
zshrc
vimrc
```

so I feel using yml, xml or various other formats would be overkill. I do not need to store indexes, paths, order or anything of the sort. However, storing the filesnames in a file separated by newlines or commas still feel kind of "dumb". How should I go about this?

**UPDATE**
It seems like my question wasn't clear enough. I know how to write to and read from files and DB using Ruby. My question was meant to be something like
 **What is the best practice for storing single-values in a file?**
Should I use a known file format like YAML or XML, or what would you choose?

Comment: Are those only file names ? Are they in the same directory ?

Comment: Those are only filenames and they are all in the same directory, ~. Always.

Answer (score 0):

through this you can get all file name in an array now you can write them to file

```
 file_names = Dir.entries(".").select {|f| !File.directory? f}
 file = File.open(local_filename, 'w')
  file_names.each do |name|
    file.write(name + "\n") 
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply go with new-line separated values or storing it inside the script. It's definitely not dumb, it's just the way you do things like that.